# Using array with index match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I initially used the array {=...} with an IF statement to have different values for the max value in a column:

```
{=IF([@Column1]*[@Column2]=MAX([Column1]*[Column2]),1.5,0.5)}
```

So if the value of column 1 in that row times the value of column 2 in that same row is the max value of the same equation applied to all the rows, the value is 1.5, otherwise the value is 0.5.

However! If e.g. [Column1] is a list of strings, where I want to use INDEX(MATCH()) to lookup a value from another table, and use it in the above formula it says #VALUE!.

```
{=IF(INDEX(Matrix1[Column6];MATCH([@[Column1]];Matrix1[Column7];0)))*[@Column2]=MAX(IF(INDEX(Matrix1[Column6];MATCH([[Column1]];Matrix1[Column7];0)))*[Column2]),1.5,0.5)}
```

My guess is that the INDEX(MATCH()) is erronious when using the array brackets "{}".

I do not know how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX` doesn't like to return an array without some manipulation, better to do it with a `SUMIF` for the second part, e.g.

`=IF(INDEX(Matrix1[Column6];MATCH([@[Column1]];Matrix1[Column7];0)))*[@Column2]=MAX(SUMIF(Matrix1[Column7];[[Column1]];Matrix1[Column6])*[Column2]);1.5;0.5)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

In this scenario `SUMIF` is being used as a "pseudo lookup" function.